# Dark bars on the top and bottom of banner ad in IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-mobile-ads

I just integrated the banner ads in IOS app. I have used a container view named "adContainerView" and when the ad is ready, I add the GADBannerView instance to adContainerView.

Code snippet for loading banner ad is

```
var bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

func createAndLoadBannerAd() {
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }
```

When the ad is loaded below event gets called and I set the height and width of the adContainerView view to that of the ad size.

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        adViewHeightConstraint.constant = bannerView.adSize.size.height
        adViewWidthConstraint.constant = bannerView.adSize.size.width
        
         bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         adContainerView.addSubview(bannerView)
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adContainerView.leadingAnchor),
             bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adContainerView.trailingAnchor),
             bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adContainerView.topAnchor),
             bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adContainerView.bottomAnchor)
         ])
    }
```

However, the ad shows up weirdly at times. It looks as below at times and this what I am expecting[image: Expected ad look]

When I go back and forth to the same page, randomly it shows up as below.[image: eNot expecting this]

I want to understand as to why I see dark bars at the top and bottom of the ad view. The adContainerView takes the exact size of the GDBannerView which is the child of adContainerView. So, technically it should never show dark bars on the top and bottom of ad.

Any pointers of why this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

BannerView can be directly added to the main view instead of adding another adContainerView to fit the size of bannerView

And also better to add any constraints in func createAndLoadBannerAd() before bannerView.load(GADRequest())

```
var bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

func createAndLoadBannerAd() {
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainView.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}
```

The above code will put the bannerView at the bottom of the mainView.

EDIT: I have used 320x100 Large banner kGADAdSizeLargeBanner and implemented as above and my ad image is also of same dimension and I didn't face any such issue so far in live version. In test mode, I don't remember getting such issue either.

Comment: Tried this but that also ended up with the same random behavior. The adContainerView in my case has a width and height constraint of zero initially. The only reason why I have a container view is to ensure that adContainerview gets a size and shows ad only when the ad loads successfully else the real state is used to display the app content.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your ad banner? Hope it is exactly 320x50 as you are using kGADAdSizeBanner.

Comment: I switched to kGADAdSizeLargeBanner and I do not see any issues. The issue is occuring only with kGADAdSizeBanner. Strange.

Comment: Probably, the ad image that are sent from Google test server is already having these top and bottom black bars in the ad image. Try printing the banner height and width if you are getting 320x50 then no need to worry and go ahead.

Comment: Yes. The banner height and width is 50 * 320.

Comment: Then, I think you are getting the banner from Google test ads server with the lines included. Probably, this is their test content. I don't think there is any problem with your code. If you want you can add a feedback in good ads page for this behavior and get the response from them. You can go ahead with ads in mean time or you can use 320x100 Large banner kGADAdSizeLargeBanner where you tested it is having no problem and then change it when you receive response.